# Can I apply for a green card without my employer's help?

Tags: usa, greencard, h1-visa

I am working in the United States on an H1B visa. My employer doesn't want to sponsor me for a green card. Is there any way I can apply for the green card by myself? Is there any such category?
I have a two master's degrees (1 outside the US) and more than a decade of work experience in IT fields.

If there is such category, is there any realistic chance of getting it?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, you can only petition yourself for employment-based immigration to the US in the following cases:

- [EB1A](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-6-part-f-chapter-2) (alien of extraordinary ability) (note that EB1B and EB1C cannot self-petition)
- [National Interest Waiver](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-6-part-f-chapter-5#S-D) (NIW), which is itself a part of EB2

Answer (score 1):

The main category for self sponsorship is [EB-1](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-first-preference-eb-1), specifically "Exceptional ability" category.

You must satisfy at least 3 out of the 10 requirements specified (see [this page](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-first-preference-eb-1)), or have an extraordinary recognition like an Oscar, a Nobel, or a similar level type of recent recognition.

Two masters and 10 years of experience will probably not cut it, but talk to an attorney for a proper evaluation of your prospects.